# End Function not Recognising - Lua

Tags: debugging, lua, love2d

I have quite the annoying bug right now, whenever I run this code

```
function player.detect()

  for j = #bullet, 1, -1 do
      if CheckCollision(bullet[j].x, bullet[j].y, bullet.w, bullet.h, enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.w, enemy.h) then
        table.remove(bullet, j)
      end
    end
  end 

  for j = #enemy, 1, -1 do
      if CheckCollision(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.w, bullet.h, enemy[j].x, enemy[j].y, enemy.w, enemy.h) then
        table.remove(enemy, j)
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

It says: Error: Syntax error: player.lua:118: '' expected near 'end'

Yes, this is player.lua, and yes the code displayed is line 104-119. Thanks for reading! Anything helps!

Comment: 1) Extra `end`s, remove them. 2) Your `bullet` table doesn't have `x` and `y` members.  Only bullet instances `bullet[j]`do have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many ends!

```
function player.detect()
  for j = #bullet, 1, -1 do
      if CheckCollision(bullet[j].x, bullet[j].y, bullet.w, bullet.h, enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.w, enemy.h) then
        table.remove(bullet, j)
    end
end

  for j = #enemy, 1, -1 do
      if CheckCollision(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.w, bullet.h, enemy[j].x, enemy[j].y, enemy.w, enemy.h) then
        table.remove(enemy, j)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks! Now is there a way to delete the enemy when the bullet collides with him? I want to make an `function enemy.die()` in the enemy file for it.

Comment: @Zach First of all, entirely dependant on what you're doing. Secondly, out of the scope of this question.